# GraphQL Java - Mutation

Tags: java, graphql

I'm trying to set up a mutation where I'm using the input type in my SDL schema

```
schema {
query: QueryType
mutation: MutationType
}

....

type Currency {
id: ID!,
name: String
code: String
...
}

type MutationType {
createCurrency(input: CurrencyInput): Currency
}

input currencyInput {
name: String!
code: String!
}
```

The query I'm passing is

```
{
"query": "mutation { createCurrency(input: $input) { id name code } }",
"variables": { "input": {"name": "NewCurrency", "code": "NCY"} }
}
```

I'm passing in the query and variables as such

```
Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();

....

// Data is a com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
variables.put("input", data.get("variables").get("input"));

ExecutionInput executionInput = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
                .query(query)
                .variables(variables)
                .build();
```

However, I keep getting a validation error

```
{message=Validation error of type UndefinedVariable: Undefined variable input @ 'createCurrency', locations=[{line=1, column=34}], extensions={classification=ValidationError}}
```

Am I passing in the variables in the wrong format?
Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: bad query/mutatation syntax ... https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: @xadm do you have an example of the SDL schema for their example?
Or can you specify what's wrong? :)

Comment: `$input: inputType ... input: $input` - two 'steps'

Comment: @xadm so basically I need to build up my query like this?
 
"query": mutation { createCurrency($input currencyInput) { createCurrency(input $input) { id name code } } }

Comment: almost, close, unecessary brackets ... read docs, try in graphiql/playground, it will hint the right syntax and highlight errors

Comment: @xadm I got the query working! :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

My request query was incorrect.
This is an example of a correct mutation query with variables

```
{
    "query": "mutation($input: CurrencyInput) { currency(input: $input) { id name code } }",
    "variables": {
        "input": {
            "name": "newName",
            "code": "NCY"
        }
    }
}
```